# How can I get the number of bytes in a newline from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

DOS/Windows newline is two (2) bytes, 0x0D0A.
UNIX/Linux newline is one (1) byte, 0x0A.
Mac newline is one (1) byte, 0x0D.

How can I write code to find the length of a newline on each platform? Output on Windows will produce two (2) bytes, but output on Linux will produce one (1) byte. I did not find anything related to this in `about_Special_Characters`.

On Windows:

```
PS C:\src\t> type .\nl.ps1
'`n'
'`n'.Length
"`n"
"`n".Length
```

Both Windows and Linux return the same result.

```
PS C:\src\t> .\nl.ps1
`n
2


1
```

Comment: Escapes aren't processed in a string literal (single quotes), which is why you see 2 for the length of the first.

Comment: `Length` property of string will only show number of characters, but not bytes. Actual number of bytes will depend on encoding you use. For example, on Windows with UTF-16 encoding newline will take 4 bytes.

Comment: As an aside when classic Mac OS became OS X in 2001, it acquired a Unix foundation, and ever since then macOS (as it is now known) has used LF-only (`0xA`) linefeeds  (not obsolete CR-only (`0xD`)) linefeeds, just like other Unix-like platforms.

Comment: And on Windows the "newline character" is not 2 bytes.  A "new line" is signified by a sequence of two characters instead of one. But "`n".length=1 on both platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) has an API for that, and is a always available from Powershell:

```
[system.environment]::newline.length
```

On Windows

```
PS> [system.environment]::newline.length
2
```

On Ubuntu

```
PS> [system.environment]::newline.length      
1
```